# SQLalchemy - query by like for float column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to query my database for records like a float variable (map coordinates) from an ajax.(querying float column). i'm not sure if the like method can query data types other than strings, because this didn't work...

```
data = json.loads(request.data)

        markers = session.query(Markers) \
        .filter( Markers.lat.like( '%' + data['lat'] + '%' ) ) \
        .filter( Markers.lng.like( '%' + data['lng'] + '%' ) ) \
        .order_by(func.random()).limit(7).all()

        if len(markers) <= 0:
            return jsonify( resp = 'no results' )
        else:
            return jsonify( resp = 'markers', markers = [m.serialize for m in markers] )
```

i even tried to make it a string with str(), but still get this error:

```
    ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: double precision ~~ unknown
LINE 3: WHERE markers.lat LIKE '%%' AND markers.lng LIKE '%%' ORDER ...
                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 'SELECT markers.id AS markers_id, markers.type AS markers_type, markers.name AS markers_name, markers.location AS markers_location, markers.lat AS markers_lat, markers.lng AS markers_lng, markers.icon AS markers_icon, markers.message AS markers_message, markers.date AS markers_date, markers.place_id AS markers_place_id, markers.owner AS markers_owner \nFROM markers \nWHERE markers.lat LIKE %(lat_1)s AND markers.lng LIKE %(lng_1)s ORDER BY random() \n LIMIT %(param_1)s' {'lng_1': '%%', 'param_1': 7, 'lat_1': '%%'}
```

what's wrong? does the sqlalchemy func module have a way of querying float columns as a string? how do i fix this? Thanks!

p.s i am using postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast float to string

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, String

markers = session.query(Markers) \
        .filter(cast(Markers.lat, String()).like('%' + data['lat'] + '%'))
```

Comment: i will give it a try.Thanks!